# WebService asmx error: Could not establish connection to network

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl, asmx

I am a WebService asmx in c# with two methods. I was published this service on external server on port 8088, for connect to this service in firewall i made port forwarding from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80(router) to 192.168.20.12:8088. In browser can connect to this web service(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Service1.asmx). Now I create a SmartDeviceProject and when add this web service on WebReference in this mode: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Service1.asmx I obtain this error:
**Unable to downloal following files from: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/Service1.asmx?wsdl**
and when add in this mode: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Service1.asmx?wsdl service *successfully add* but in this case in code:

```
        public Service1() {
            this.Url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/Service1.asmx";
        }
```

When I execute a project obtain this error: **Could not establish connection to network**
I get this error and if remove in all code port 8088 from Url.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the proxy instance, set the Url property to the correct value, just like the constructor sets it to the wrong value:

```
using (var proxy = new Service1())
{
    proxy.Url = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Service1.asmx";
    // use the proxy to call operations on the service
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean, "doesn't work"? Was there an exception?

Comment: I resolved this bug, thank's.The problem was in internet connection from mobile emulator.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, in SmartDevice projects (i.e. PocketPC) this exception means that you don't have access to a network.

If you are running this in the emulator, then you need to ensure that both the emulator and the emulated device are configured to connect to either the internet or your local network, depending on where the service is hosted.

Comment: I think you're right becouse I created one project in asp.net and I was connected to web service and her methods.

Comment: I must connect to Internet in this mode: On mobile application emulator: File -> Configure... -> Network -> check Enable NE2000 PCMCIA network adapter and bind to: -> select my network card with internet (but I must install Virtual PC 2007).

Comment: If you have the network emulator configured, then you must also cradle the device in the emulator in order for the network to be connected. This is an often overlooked and underdocumented requirement.

Comment: Here a good tutorial to connect Emulator to Internet : http://www.betterthaneveryone.com/archive/2008/08/31/getting-network-access-on-the-windows-mobile-emulator.aspx